# How to set the font size in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplotly

I have made a ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotly)

f1 <- diamonds |> group_by(cut,clarity,color) |>  count() |> 
  group_by(cut) |> mutate(N=sum(n)) |> 
      ggplot() +
      aes(
        x =  cut,
        y = n,
        fill = cut
      ) +
      geom_col() +
      theme(legend.position = "none")+
      coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(vars(clarity))
f1
```

I want to convert to `ggplotly` object

```
ggplotly(f1)%>% 
        layout(legend=list(font = list(size = 8)), 
            xaxis = list(titlefont = list(size = 8), tickfont = list(size = 8)),
            yaxis = list(titlefont = list(size = 8), tickfont = list(size = 8)))
```

However, the size of text is only changed in the 1st subplot. I would like to have the size applied to all subplots:

[image]

The issue is I have it in a function so number of facets varies, so this post was not helpful: [R ggplotly with facet_wrap : axis tick size not changing for all plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303856/r-ggplotly-with-facet-wrap-axis-tick-size-not-changing-for-all-plots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the answer in the referenced post you have to style **each** axis separately, i.e. in contrast to `ggplot2` each subplot or facet in `plotly` has it's own axis. As a consequence, `xaxis` and `yaxis` will only have an effect on the first row or column of the facet panels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly, warn=FALSE)

axis <- list(tickfont = list(size = 8))

ggplotly(f1) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = axis,
    xaxis2 = axis,
    xaxis3 = axis,
    yaxis = axis,
    yaxis2 = axis,
    yaxis3 = axis
  )
```

[image]

For that reason IMHO the easier approach would be to style your axes directly in `ggplot2` using `theme` options:

```r
f2 <- f1 +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 6))

ggplotly(f2)
```

[image]